# Ajax to change button text and functionality when no more results

Tags: ajax, wordpress

have a button that I want to change text and disable if there're no more results from the Wordpress query.

The Wordpress query works as expected, `$query->max_num_pages` returns number of pages. The load more function also works as it should. But I can't get the function for changing the button CTA to work. It always displays like there's more pages to load.

Ajax:

```
  var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    var page = 2;
    jQuery(function($){
        // init isotope
        var $grid = $('.team-content');
        $grid.isotope({
          // options
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows',
          percentPosition: true,
          transitionDuration: '0s', 
          hiddenStyle: {
            opacity: 0
          },
          visibleStyle: {
            opacity: 1
          }
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.loadmore-team', function(e){

          var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_team"); ?>'
          };

          $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            if (response != '') {
              var $answer = $(response);

              //append items to grid
              $grid.append($answer)
              .isotope('appended', $answer);

              // layaout on imagesLoaded
              $grid.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $grid.isotope('layout');
              });
              page++;
            } else {
                alert(response)
              $('.loadmore-team').text("No more Post!");
              $('.loadmore-team').attr("disabled", true);
              $('.loadmore-team').css("borderColor", "gray");
              $('.loadmore-team').css("color", "gray");
            }
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Functions.php

```
// load more function by ajax
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_team');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_team');

function load_posts_by_ajax_team(){
  check_ajax_referer('load_more_team', 'security');
  $paged= $_POST['page'];

  $args = array(

    'post_type' => 'team',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged,
  );

  $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($my_posts-> have_posts()) { ?>

    <?php
      while($my_posts-> have_posts()){
        $my_posts-> the_post();

        $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "team-location" );
        $termsSlug = ""; //initialize the variable that will contain the terms
        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term
        $termsSlug .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs
        }

         ?>
              <?php   get_template_part( 'template-parts/team', 'listing' ); ?>
    <?php  }
    ?>
<?php  }

wp_die();
}
```

Query:

```
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'team',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1), //page number 1 on load
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);

                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    
                    $termsArray = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'team-location');

                    $termsSLug = "";
                    foreach ($termsArray as $term) {
                        $termsSLug .= $term->slug . ' ';
                    }
        ?>
         <?php get_template_part('template-parts/team', 'listing'); ?>
        <?php   }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>  
                
    </div>
     <?php if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) { ?>
                  <div class="button_load_more ">
                            <a  class="btn btn-default button loadmore-team" href="#"><?php printf( __( 'Load more', 'bizniz-tools' )); ?></a>

                  </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

Any clue anyone?

EDIT:--------------------------------

"Response" outputs [image] for the first click on the button, and [image] for the second click. Just as expected since there's just one more page to load.

EDIT 2: --------------------------------

Ok, so I came to realize that the output of the data wasn't empty if there were no more posts to show. I edited the following line to also include empty spaces etc as empty

`if (response.replace(/^\s*$/, "").length > 0) {`

So now the script kinda work, but when I've reached the last post, the button doesn't change automatically. I need to click on it once more. I'd like to avoid this last click. Any ideas?

Comment: When you run the query, there's a result that will be used and that should be empty if no more pages, what does the console log says about "response"?

Comment: @OldPadawan thanks for your answer. I've now updated the post with two screenshots of the output of "Response"

Comment: Does the js alert triggers when results is empty?

Comment: @OldPadawan yes, seems like it does. The console displays empty outputs for every click after last post is loaded.

Comment: The js alert works, pops and shows 0, right? But the css isn't applied? Have you tried the $('.loadmore-team').prop('disabled', true)?

Comment: @OldPadawan Ok, so I've come to realize that whatever I put inside the `else` doesn't execute. The `if` works tho.. I put a `$('.loadmore-team').text("Have more posts");` there and the text changes on click.

Comment: I would make the 'ajaxurl' page to send a numbered response and treat it. i.e. you have some results > 0 then show the link to next page, if result == 0 then the else would make more sense and fire. In your case, 'response' should be 0 to trigger the grey-ish disabled button.

Comment: @OldPadawan I've now updated my original post. I've made the response function also to include blank spaces etc as "empty". Half way there!

Comment: My thoughts: you search for a number of pages ($query->max_num_pages) and you also should have the number of results (i.e. 38 results => 4 results on page #1 + 8 pages of 4 results + 1 last page of 2 results). 4 + 32 + 2 = 38. I'd work around the number of results, not the number of pages. Because when you get 36 results (4 * 9), you'll have an empty page at the end, unless you do # of pages-1 to know you need to disable the button. How do you count results and pages?